# Does Apache Twill relaunch containers that are killed by Yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-twill

Yarn kills containers when there is heavy load in the cluster. How does Apache Twill react when one of its runnablse running in the container gets killed? Does its run with reduced number of instances of the runnable or does it relaunch it?

Answer (score 0):

By default twill will keep trying re-launch the instances indefinitely.  As of version 0.10.0, you are able to specify a maximum number of retries.